# Remove one element in each row from a solved Sudoku puzzle

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I am trying to create a method that will remove one random element in each row from a solved Sudoku matrix that I have generated. How can I achieved this?

Solved Sudoku Generator:

```
public static void generate_Sud (int n, int [][] S){ // Generates Sudoku method 
    for (int r=0; r<=n-1; r++){
        int startNum = (int) (Math.sqrt(n) * (r % Math.sqrt(n)) + (r/Math.sqrt(n)));
        for (int c=0; c<=n-1; c++){
            S[r][c] = ((startNum + c) % n) + 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

[Sudoku Matrix Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq5M4.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a 3x3 Sodoku:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int randomPosition = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)  //Random number between 0 and 2
    S[i][randomPosition] = -1; // -1 or whatever you use to represent blank
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just changed the 3 to S.length so that any n x n grid can remove any one element.